# Migrate LDAP from one machine to another

Tags: linux, ldap, migration

My current task is to migrate the content from one machine (source) to another (target). Both machines are identical. One is heavily used and the other is clean.

I already have all the files that are different between both machines and what files are not in the target (they must be copied from the source).

The problem is, how should I transfer the LDAP data?

Is that just a copy from one side to another or should I dump some data from some place and then reload it in the target?

Any good documentation on how to do that? I couldn't find any.

Note: I will worry about other stuff like DB later. Right now, my headache is LDAP.

Comment: Here is similar with a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792563/how-do-i-clone-an-openldap-database

Answer (score 4):

I recently had the same problem. [This answer at serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/a/796163/154648) worked for me. Basically, these are the steps:

On the 'old' machine run the following commands to export the configuration and the data, respectively:

```
# service slapd stop
# slapcat -n 0 -l backup-ldap-config.ldif
# slapcat -n 1 -l backup-ldap-database.ldif
```

Install OpenLDAP on the new machine (no need to configure anything) and copy the two `ldif` backup files to it.

On the new machine, stop the `slapd` service and move the existing LDAP configuration out of the way:

```
# systemctl stop slapd
# mv /etc/ldap/{slapd.d,slapd.d-backup-after-fresh-install}
```

Create a new directory with the proper ownership and import the config part of the LDAP server:

```
# mkdir /etc/ldap/slapd.d
# chown openldap:openldap /etc/ldap/slapd.d
# slapadd -n 0 -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d -l backup-ldap-config.ldif
_#################### 100.00% eta   none elapsed            none fast!
Closing DB...
# chown -R openldap:openldap /etc/ldap/slapd.d
```

Import the data part of the backup and set the correct ownership:

```
# slapadd -n 1 -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d -l backup-ldap-database.ldif
*#################### 100.00% eta   none elapsed             02s spd 148.9 k/s
Closing DB...
# chown -R openldap:openldap /var/lib/ldap
```

And start the LDAP server:

```
# systemctl start slapd
```

In my case, the old machine was running Ubuntu 12.04 and the new one runs Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: This solution works like a charm but I could not login on the new server. It seems that ldap root password was not copied.

Comment: A quick update: I just reused my solution above to migrate the content of the LDAP server on Ubuntu 18.04 (OpenLDAP v2.4.42) to a new one on Ubuntu 20.04 (OpenLDAP v2.4.49). It still works

Comment: Still works with migrating 20.04 (v2.4) to 22.04 (v2.5) if you make some changes to the config.ldif before importing it. See https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/service-migrating-from-openldap-2-4-x-to-2-5-x/23807

Answer (score 0):

There is standard LDAP migration procedure provided by the vendors of LDAP check for details/documentation from respective vendor's support or user forums or you could also try perl scripts/tools available for migration (caution: try the scripts on test server and apply on production servers)

Below link should help you to some extent

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LDAP-HOWTO/ldapmigrationtools.html

Comment: All links are dead on this page.